# Zorin 15 won't reboot

Tags: linux, busybox, fsck

I went to reboot my notebook running Zorin 15 and all that come up is a Busybox test saying to type help and upon doing that something called Initramfs shows. I can't get the computer to boot up to anything else and after poking around a little I got some reports with the last line as below

```
the root filesystem on /dev/mapper/zorin--vg-root requires a manual fsck
```

After reading up on this some suggested booting to grub and follow certain paths which none of them seem to get results.

Comment: Have you tried running `fsck /dev/mapper/zorin--vg-root` at the prompt? There's also another answer that suggests `fsck -y /dev/mapper/zorin--vg-root` (https://askubuntu.com/questions/888835/how-do-i-do-a-manual-fsck#answer-888839).

Comment: I did run the fsck -y script and that eventually got me back into Zorin. What I also found out was there appears to be HD errors as a couple different tests failed so I am replacing the drive, Thanks